# Can't get approximation of sine function to work in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've tried this every way I can think of and am at wits end.  I'm trying to write the sine approximation in Haskell.  I think the issue I'm having has something to do with type declarations, but I'm not sure.

Here's my code:

```
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial (n-1)

summation' f x 1 = f (x 1)
summation' f x n = f (x n) + f (x n-1)

sineX x i = (((-1)^i)/factorial(2*i+1))*(x^(2*i+1))

sineXApprox x n = summation' sineX x n
```

As you can see, I've split up the the function into three sub functions.

Here's the error I'm getting when I try inputting "sineXApprox 2 2" into ghci (btw I'm using ghci on command prompt):

```
<interactive>:503:1:
    Could not deduce (Num (a0 -> a1))
      arising from the ambiguity check for `it'
    from the context (Num (a1 -> a1),
                      Num (a -> a1),
                      Num a,
                      Integral a1,
                      Fractional a1,
                      Eq a)
      bound by the inferred type for `it':
                 (Num (a1 -> a1), Num (a -> a1), Num a, Integral a1, Fractional a1,
                  Eq a) =>
                 a1 -> a1
      at <interactive>:503:1-8
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    When checking that `it'
      has the inferred type `forall a a1.
                             (Num (a1 -> a1), Num (a -> a1), Num a, Integral a1, Fractional a1,
                              Eq a) =>
                             a1 -> a1'
    Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

Any help you can offer is appreciated!

Comment: try to use `fromIntegral` to convert `Int -> Double`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: your parenthesis are wrong. Try

```
summation' f x 1 = f x 1
summation' f x n = f x n + f x (n-1)
```

Yes, it has something to do with type declarations - rather the absence of them.
In `f (x 1)`, Haskell interprets `x` as a function, something you surely did not mean. Add

```
summation' :: (Double -> Double -> Double) -> Double -> Double -> Double
```

in your first step and see how the error message changes. Also add type signatures for all other functions.

Haskell's type-checking is quite powerful, which has the downside that when you write something you did not mean, it still tries to make some sense out of it. The error message is shifted away. With explicit type signatures, you can locate the problem more easily.

Actually, some of these parameters should rather be `Int`s than `Doubles`, but this opens another can of worms...

Comment: Thank you.  That fixed (most) of my problems.  I was convinced that I was just doing the type declarations wrong...but after your suggestion, I went back and kindof brute forced it.  The only problem I have now is that it doesn't seem to want to divide a Double by an Int (Couldn't match expected type 'Double' with actual type 'Int').

Comment: Throw `fromIntegral` at it to convert from `Int` to `Double`.